# BigQuery partition on calendar week

Tags: google-bigquery

Every week, I get a new dataset that I need to insert in BigQuery. The data can arrive on any day of the week. Once the data is ingested, I want to query data that arrived last week.

One option is to use date as partitioning when the data arrived but then the developers would need to know the exact date when data arrived to query the partition.

Instead of this, while ingestion, I want to create an INTEGER column which represents the calendar week of the year. The format will be 202005 or 202153 where former represents fifth week of 2020 and latter represents second last week of year 2021.

Since this is an integer, the only option for partition seems to be range partitioning. For it, BigQuery is asking for a start, end and interval. What values should I define?

I can define the following but as you can imagine that this sounds wrong

```
start 202001
end 203054
inerval 1
```

Update:
It seems that bigquery will only create partitions for which it has data. I checked that by executing

```
#legacySQL
SELECT 
project_id, dataset_id, table_id, partition_id, TIMESTAMP(creation_time/1000) AS creation_time
FROM [PROJECT_ID:DATASET_ID.TABLE_ID$__PARTITIONS_SUMMARY__]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to still Partition by date - but not ingestion date or whatever date you have in mind, rather start date of respective week with the help of [DATE_TRUNC](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date_trunc) function

```
DATE_TRUNC(your_date, WEEK)
```

Note: You even can define start day of the week

> WEEK(): Truncates date_expression to the preceding week boundary, where weeks begin on WEEKDAY. Valid values for WEEKDAY are SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, and SATURDAY.

Comment: Cool. This would also work. Btw, regarding the solution that I mentioned for using integer partitioning, what would big query do internally?

If my start is start 202001, end is 203054 and interval is 1, then would bigquery at the time of table declaration, create all the partitions? Or partition are only created when the data arrives for a partition? Because if latter is true, then integer partitioning could also be used since for each year only 54 partitions would be created and this would be ideal.

Comment: You can experiment with using int. meantime consider to vote up if answer was helpful :o) and accept too if you think you can use this solution  :o)

Comment: Bad thing that SO doesn't allow to edit your vote after 5 mins. This doesn't work as 
BQ doesn't allow it 
`PARTITION BY expression must be DATE(<timestamp_column>), DATE(<datetime_column>), DATETIME_TRUNC(<datetime_column>, DAY/HOUR/MONTH/YEAR), a DATE column, TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(<timestamp_column>, DAY/HOUR/MONTH/YEAR), DATE_TRUNC(<date_column>, MONTH/YEAR), or RANGE_BUCKET(<int64_column>, GENERATE_ARRAY(<int64_value>, <int64_value>[, <int64_value>]))
`

Comment: @codisfy - if you think it does not work for you - post your question with all details and I will be happy to help :o)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Thanks, I think asking another question won't help, partitioning on a Week is not allowed yet. The error that you will get is what I posted in the last comment. On a `PARTITION BY`
`DATE_TRUNC` only allows  `MONTH/YEAR`.

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery does not allow partitioning by week yet, as noted in the comments on @mikhail berlyant's answer.
One work around could be to first create a DATE column using the DATE_TRUNC function and only then use it for partitioning

```
CREATE TABLE your_table
PARTITION BY partition_column
AS
SELECT *, DATE(DATE_TRUNC(your_date_column, WEEK)) as partition_column FROM your_other_table
```